# How to take input and split it up into string and int. splitting into XXX, YYY

Tags: python, input

first off thanks on my conquest of learning python, very newbie question.
I want to take input from a user, so obviously I use

```
userinput = input("INFO: Enter the user intput: ")
```

I want the user to input something along the lines Dogs123456, 
how can I remove String "Dogs" and turn 123 and 456 into their own separate usable variables.
Thus allowing me to create something with just the numbers and not the text entered. so I want to split up any number entered after the text into two variables, x which will be the first 3 numbers in the format XXX and y which will be the next three numbers in the format YYY. basically.

for example: for example 192.XXX.YYY.02 or how ever I want to format it for other reasons.

Edit:

I would prefer to ideally split up the input, so that the numbers can be placed in variables in sets of Two, or Three for learning sake. So again the user would enter something along the lines of ABC123456, and I would want to take that input remove, the ABC - as I know they are going to enter in ABC, and just take XXX, YYY and store those values to reuse....I hope i have explained it somewhat.
So I am than reusing the code in this kind of way

```
"192." + XXX + YYY + ".21"
```

The XXX will become 123 and the YYY 456, I am looking to understand how I can  take those numbers from the original string and turn it into something reusable. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but... still unclear. How do you determine what numbers to turn into XX and YY? Like in your second example, how can you determine that specifically _those_ numbers turn into XX?

Comment: Do you want to simply store those numbers to variable? "*04 to YY"* -- I'm not sure I understand that.

Comment: Also, try it first yourself. Read [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And don't repost it without editing. It doesn't get closed just randomly. Try to imagine reading your question without knowing your code, and provide enough information to reproduce it. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for advice. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is exactly what you wanted because the question is a bit unclear. But If you know the length of the input beforehand and you know what portions of the string you want you can go ahead and split it into parts. For example in the following.

```
userinput = input("INFO: Enter the user intput: ")

final_output = "192.{}.{}.21".format(userinput[3:6], userinput[6:9])
print(final_output)
```

I input

```
ABC123456
```

it prints

```
192.123.456.21
```

What i did was I took your string from position 3 to position 6 which is the first three numbers which are 123, and then position 6 to 9 which is 456, You can use this to take any parts you need.

Comment: Thank you I know my question was unclear, but this was correct ! You have read my mind my friend. Thank you again!

Comment: aye no problem brother.

Answer (score 2):

As @pm980's answer pointed out, if you know the exact location, then you're good to go. But what if you don't know anything about the input? Luckily there are [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) and the [Python `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Using `findall`, you can find all the strings that match. Then you can `join` them and do whatever you want with it. So import `re` and create your regex:

```py
import re
numRegex = re.compile(r'\d+')
```

This regex matches any unsigned number. Now, get the numbers out of your string:

```py
numbers = numRegex.findall(userInput)
```

And now `join` them, so things like `Dog12s345` will resolve to `12345` (useful for spaces and periods):

```py
number = ''.join(numbers)
```

And we are done! Keep in your mind that `number` is still a string - I don't know how you want to split it. If you ask for it, and provide the exact explanation, I will add it also.

Comment: Thank you, this was also very helpful in my quest for education. I Really appreciate this